# Couchdb returning Invalid Json

Tags: json, couchdb

Trying to learn Views in CouchDB, from the book, but I keep coming across this issue, for some reason, this is a bad request and is invalid JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : "_design/example",
    "language" : "javascript",
    "views" : {
    "foo" : {
        "map" : "function(doc) { if (doc.date && doc.title) { emit(doc.date, doc.title);}}"
    }
    }
}
```

Yet this is fine:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/tyres_used",
    "language": "javascript",
    "views": {
    "tyres": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.tyres && doc.client) {\n emit(doc.tyres, doc.client);\n} \n}"
    }
    }
}
```

The only way I can upload docs at the moment is to alter the second script with the words from the first then it goes in. I have no idea what I did on the first one though to get it to work.

Apologies if this comes out looking wrong, I have never done this block quote before.

Comment: Can we have the "error you received"?

Comment: Hi yes, here is the complete command line interaction
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/views_testing/_design/example -d @example.json
    Warning: Couldn't read data from file "example.json", this makes an empty 
    Warning: POST.
    {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}                                                                                                                                                            I don't know how to format this correctly as a reply sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The first error you are receiving is because cURL can't find the file. Make sure the file is in the same directory where you're executing your command to specify the relative/absolute path to the file.

Next, you'll face a Content-type error. You need to specify what type of data you are sending to CouchDB.To specify the JSON Content-type header with cURL, do the following :

`curl -X PUT 127.0.0.1:5984/views_testing/_design/example -d @example.json -H "Content-type: application/json"`

Comment: Getting the same error with this I'm afraid. I think it is something to do with the file, as I can modify the one that works and it will upload, but I won't always be using this particular computer to load this so that is fairly impractical

Comment: Well, is the file in the same directory where you execute the command?If you run the **ls** command, you see your example.json file right?

Comment: I need to apologise, I have solved this and it is a school boy error, but hopefully it will help someone else, I was not in the same directory as the file I was uploading, so it was looking for a file that was not there. Thank you for your input, it made me think properly.

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clearer for other users to see what was the problem and what was the solution to your question. Please accept my answer if it helped you.